# Django-q: WARNING reincarnated worker Process-1:1 after timeout

Tags: django, redis, django-q, django-redis

I've installed and configured Django-Q 1.3.5 (on Django 3.2 with Redis 3.5.3 and Python 3.8.5).
This is my Cluster configuration:

```
# redis defaults
Q_CLUSTER = {
    'name': 'my_broker',
    'workers': 4,
    'recycle': 500,
    'timeout': 60,
    'retry': 65,
    'compress': True,
    'save_limit': 250,
    'queue_limit': 500,
    'cpu_affinity': 1,
    'redis': {
        'host': 'localhost',
        'port': 6379,
        'db': 0,
        'password': None,
        'socket_timeout': None,
        'charset': 'utf-8',
        'errors': 'strict',
        'unix_socket_path': None
    }
}
```

where I have appropriately chosen `timeout:60` and `retry:65` to explain my problem.
I created this simple function to call via Admin Scheduled Task:

```
def test_timeout_task():
    time.sleep(61)
    return "Result of task"
```

And this is my "Scheduled Task page" (localhost:8000/admin/django_q/schedule/)

| ID | Name | Func | Success |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test timeout | mymodel.tasks.test_timeout_task | ? |

When I run this task, I get the following warning:

```
10:18:21 [Q] INFO Process-1 created a task from schedule [test timeout]
10:19:22 [Q] WARNING reincarnated worker Process-1:1 after timeout
10:19:22 [Q] INFO Process-1:7 ready for work at 68301
```

and the task is no longer executed.

So, my question is: is there a way to correctly handle an unpredicted task?

Answer (score 1):

You can set your timeout to :
`'timeout': None` and it should handle your task without stopping.